# How to Show $(0,\infty ) $ is connected in $R_k$ topology?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I wanted to show that $(0,\infty ) $ is connected in $R_k$ topology.

OPen set in $R_k$ is $(a,b)$ or $(a,b)\setminus K $where $K=\{1/n \mid n\in \mathbb N\}$

As open interval In  $(1,\infty ) $ in R and k topology same so connected 
On the contrary if not

$(0,1) = C\cup B$ where $C$ and $B$ are open

How to arrive at the contradiction that I don't get

Please, can anyone give me a hint so that I can complete this?

ANy Help will be appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by $(a, b) K$ here?

Comment: Are you saying that these *are* the open sets of your topology or that they're a basis for the topology?  Either way I see a problem.  If they *are* the open sets, I don't think you've defined a topology at all because the union of two disjoint open intervals is not open.  If they are a basis, then I don't see what $(a, b) \setminus K$ adds because all sets of this form are a union of open intervals.

Comment: Sorry Sir for that . Actually I wanted to define K-topology as it is generated by (a,b) and (a,b)\K

Answer (score 2):

On $(0, \infty)$ the usual topology and that of $\mathbb{R}_K$ coincide, as $K$ is closed in $(0,\infty)$ in both subspace topologies. As it is connected in the usual one, it's connected in both.